# Three stage nested design with one replicate runs out of degrees of freedom

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I am trying to use a three stage nested design to do an analysis on incomes for different households. The data can be visualized as follows:

```
                  State 1             State 2             State 3
             Town 1    Town 2    Town 1    Town 2    Town 1    Town 2
Household 1  10        7         6         6         15        12
Household 2  13        12        5         12        18        15
Household 3  16        11        9         7         20        18
Household 4  12        9         3         10        19        16
```

Where `Household` is nested in `Town`, which is nested in `State`. The problem that I'm running into is a lack of replication within levels of the nested design. I've done similar analyses but I had multiple measurements, with this data I'm just working with the mean incomes of household. When I try and fit the models

```
house.mod1 <- aov(Income ~ State + State:Town + State:Town:Household)
house.mod2 <- lmer(Income ~ 1 + (1|State) + (1|State:Town) + (1|State:Town:Household))
```

I'm left without any degrees of freedom for the error term and so I can't try to estimate the variance components. Is this even possible to do with only one replicate or am I just thinking of the data and the model in the wrong way?

Comment: This design suffers from single replicate issue e.g., there is no replications. Thus, you cannot fit the full model since there will be no degrees of freedom to estimate the error. A usual solution is to pull the higher order term into the error. Replication is the key in statistical inference.

Answer (score 1):

The main question,as usual is: what are you trying to study? Presumably it is not the individual households.

The setup you have here is an extension of a randomized block design (which has only two levels). In a randomized block design, you simply leave out the interaction term between the two levels (because you do not have enough observations/degrees of freedom).

In your instance, it is probably best to leave out the three-way interaction
State$*$Town$*$Household.